# How to use ng-selected and ng-options together?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I'm populating a dropdown box using ng-options like this

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names"></select>
```

I need to select an option by default, I tried `ng-selected`, but it seems like that can be used with `ng-repeat` only.
Another option I found is setting the value `$scope.selectedName = 1;` in controller. But is there any way to set the default value in template.

Comment: you need to set at controller the default value for selectedName: selectedName = names[0], for example

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo I have mentioned that in the question. Is there any way we can set in in the template

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to set it in the controller. It's clear, however, that you want a template solution. If you are committed to HTML you can use ng-init (although not a "best practice").

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names" ng-init="selectedName=names[0]"></select>
```

Comment: here has a small problem... if the options had loaded from from a rest service, the init will generate an err. If the list is defined on controller, there are no problem.

Comment: very true, I suppose you could use a  ternary expression in the ng-init as a fail safe, but this is only if the template solution is an absolute requirement.